# HDMI-CEC Working on some commands using adb

Tags: adb, hdmi, hdmi-cec

I have mecool tv box connected with hdmi and samsung tv connected as well. when i gave standby command using adb my tv goes to standby but when i gave any other commands it can't work.
e.g

```
# echo 0x40 0x36 > /sys/class/cec/cmd
```

this command working for standby.

```
 # echo 0x40 0x8F> /sys/class/cec/cmd
 # echo 0x80 0x82> /sys/class/cec/cmd
```

these commands didn't display anything on screen or tv. i am taking help about commands from this website [cec-o-matic](http://www.cec-o-matic.com/)

Comment: I'm try to turn off/on and volume up/down through hdmi-cec, but I didn't get a proper command to do it. Do you know? How we can do this.

Comment: which tv you have?

Comment: I've made my android tv device and i'm working on Orient and Samsung TV

Comment: @ZaighamRaza did you find any work around !!

Comment: @ParthPitroda what you are trying to do? may be i can help

Comment: i am try to turn on/off tv from custom android device.

Comment: @ParthPitroda   0x40 0x04 is the command to turn on TV. first 0x40 specify the hdmi port where tv is attached with android device. for example it could be 0x10,0x20,0x30 according to port and 0x04 is turn on tv command.
once you figured put to which port you device is connected then use 0x40 0x36 command to turn off.
you can get more help by contacting me via linkedin

Comment: @ZaighamRaza i want to know about how to execute command

Comment: right now i am fire command from terminal for testing purpose so now i want to execute commands from android device to tv for this i need ur help